# how to resolve the conversation error in python

Tags: python, chatterbot

U as busy trying to train my chatbot but every time I run the code I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Amank\OneDrive\Documents\chatbot\index.py", line 12, in <module>
    trainer.train(cleaned_corpus)
  File "C:\Users\Amank\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot\trainers.py", line 96, in train
    for conversation_count, text in enumerate(conversation):
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is the code:

```
def train(self, conversation):
    """
    Train the chat bot based on the provided list of
    statements that represents a single conversation.
    """
    previous_statement_text = None
    previous_statement_search_text = ''

    statements_to_create = []

    for conversation_count, text in enumerate():
        if self.show_training_progress:
            utils.print_progress_bar(
                'List Trainer',
                conversation_count + 1, len(conversation)
            )

        statement_search_text = self.chatbot.storage.tagger.get_bigram_pair_string(text)

        statement = self.get_preprocessed_statement(
            Statement(
                text=text,
                search_text=statement_search_text,
                in_response_to=previous_statement_text,
                search_in_response_to=previous_statement_search_text,
                conversation='training'
            )
        )

        previous_statement_text = statement.text
        previous_statement_search_text = statement_search_text

        statements_to_create.append(statement)

    self.chatbot.storage.create_many(statements_to_create)


class ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(Trainer):
"""
Allows the chat bot to be trained using data from the
ChatterBot dialog corpus.
"""

def train(self, *corpus_paths):
    from chatterbot.corpus import load_corpus, list_corpus_files

    data_file_paths = []

    # Get the paths to each file the bot will be trained with
    for corpus_path in corpus_paths:
        data_file_paths.extend(list_corpus_files(corpus_path))

    for corpus, categories, file_path in load_corpus(*data_file_paths):

        statements_to_create = []

        # Train the chat bot with each statement and response pair
        for conversation_count, conversation in enumerate(corpus):

            if self.show_training_progress:
                utils.print_progress_bar(
                    'Training ' + str(os.path.basename(file_path)),
                    conversation_count + 1,
                    len(corpus)
                )

            previous_statement_text = None
            previous_statement_search_text = ''

            for text in conversation:

                statement_search_text = self.chatbot.storage.tagger.get_bigram_pair_string(text)

                statement = Statement(
                    text=text,
                    search_text=statement_search_text,
                    in_response_to=previous_statement_text,
                    search_in_response_to=previous_statement_search_text,
                    conversation='training'
                )

                statement.add_tags(*categories)

                statement = self.get_preprocessed_statement(statement)

                previous_statement_text = statement.text
                previous_statement_search_text = statement_search_text

                statements_to_create.append(statement)

        self.chatbot.storage.create_many(statements_to_create)
```

I tried changing the argument and function but that didn't help.

Comment: This is really difficult to follow, but based on what you have posted you are trying to iterate something that is NoneType (conversation?).  You need to figure out why that is NoneType and not iterable.

Comment: `enumerate()` with no argument is a type error. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The error is telling you that `conversation` is `None` and therefore cannot be enumerated. However, we don't have enough information to be able to tell you more than that. Additionally your code doesn't match the code in your error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With this limited information I can just say:

It looks like you are getting a **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable** error when you try to train your chat bot using a list of statements. This error means that you are trying to loop over an object that has a value of **None**, which is not possible.

One possible cause of this error is that you forgot to add a **return** statement to a function that should return an iterable object, such as a list or a string. In your case, maybe the **conversation** parameter is None because it was not returned by another function.

To fix this error, you need to make sure that the object you want to iterate over is not None and has been assigned an iterable value.

You can also use a **try-except** block to catch the TypeError and handle it gracefully. (This last bit is just glazing)

Comment: @Aman_vdub maybe you could answer this answer if it was helpful